# python config to disable blend1 files

Tags: python

I'm quite new to blender. But I'm using python only and the bpy module.
It keeps making the backup files `blend1` even though I disabled it in the settings (save versions = 0)

Do I need some python magic to disable it as well?
Not sure it it's relevant but I'm using `bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile` to save to a orignal blend file.

Comment: for me the blend1 file doesn't get generated when i set save versions = 0. in blender 3.4

Comment: Hi @HarryMcKenzie, are you using bpy as well? Non GUI

Comment: yes bpy as well. i noticed blend1 got generated with bpy but then not anymore after setting it to zero in pref